# Delphi 2010+ and "Left side cannot be assigned to" in read-only records: can this be disabled?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I know [what changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620506/left-side-cannot-be-assigned-to-for-record-type-properties-in-delphi). I know why. But..

```
TComplicatedCallMaker = record
    Param1: TRecordType;
    Param2: TRecordType;
    {...}
    Param15: TRecordType;
    procedure Call;
end;

function ComplicatedCall: TComplicatedCallMaker;
begin
 { Fill default param values }
end;

procedure DoingSomeWorkHere;
begin
  with ComplicatedCall do begin
    Param7 := Value7;
    Param12 := Value12;
    Call;
  end;
end;
```

This has perfectly worked before Delphi 2010. An extremely useful technique for making calls which accept a load of parameters but usually only need two or three. Never the same ones though.

And now it gives... guess what?

```
E2064: Left side cannot be assigned to.
```

Can't this helpful new behavior be disabled somehow? Any ideas on how to modify the pattern so it works?

Because seriously, losing such a handy technique (and rewriting a bunch of code) for no apparent reason...

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Left side cannot be assigned to" for record type properties in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620506/left-side-cannot-be-assigned-to-for-record-type-properties-in-delphi)

Comment: I'm very surprised that ever worked.

Comment: @David Hefferman: Why? It's a perfectly valid trick. No hacking, just language features.

Comment: It was removed because it was never supposed to be allowed in the first place.

Comment: I don't get the comparison of this question with the [what changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620506/left-side-cannot-be-assigned-to-for-record-type-properties-in-delphi) reference. Especially since properties always behaved the way as that topic describes, it never "changed".

Comment: @NGLN: It's the same change. Back then you could retrieve read-only property and pretend to "set it's fields". In fact you were changing the copy, not the property itself. Now it's explicitly disabled, and so my code broke too.

Comment: @himself `Rec.A := ARec.A;` also produces a _Left side cannot be assigned to_ compiler error in Delphi 7. With `with`, you can get around, but that is thís question.

Comment: @Ngln, you've never been able to directly modify the fields of a record returned by a function (or a property, backed by a function), but it used to be that by wrapping the function call in a `with` statement, as shown in this question, you could circumvent the compiler's checking. It was never supposed to work that way, but due to an oversight in the compiler, it was allowed. Newer versions of Delphi corrected that mistake.

Comment: @Rob Yes, I already understood that. I just found it a bit strange that OP compared this `with` not working from D2010 to something that never changed as also being changed. Never mind.

Answer (score 3):

I find it a little surprising that this ever worked but since you say it did I'm sure you are right.  I'd guess the change was made without consideration for record methods.  Without the ability to call methods then this construct would be rather pointless.

Anyway, the compiler isn't going to let you off the hook on this one so you'll have to do this:

```
type
  TRecordType = record end;
  TComplicatedCallMaker = record
    Param1: TRecordType;
    procedure Call;
  end;

function ComplicatedCall: TComplicatedCallMaker;
begin
 { Fill default param values }
end;

procedure DoingSomeWorkHere(const Value: TRecordType);
var
  CallMaker: TComplicatedCallMaker;
begin
  CallMaker := ComplicatedCall;
  with CallMaker do begin
    Param1 := Value;
    Call;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that straight away too and it works. But this kills half the beauty... are there really no other ways?

Comment: You could use an instance of a class but then you'd have to free it

Comment: Yup, and it's way slower than (probably stack-allocated!) return records.

Comment: There was no beauty here to kill. It's all pure ugly hack that previously relied on a broken compiler.  The compiler is fixed now.

Comment: @Warren P: No it's not. Hacking is working against the compiler. This trick relied on documented, expected behavior. Say what you want, although this usage was unexpected to compiler developers, it was legit. Unexpected usage != hacking. In fact, trying to limit what you can do to stuff *explicitly stated you can do* is killing the otherwise rich language.

Comment: Undefined and against what any compiler designer or language specifier would have expected. If you don't get that, then all I ask is don't ever inflict a compiler on anybody, okay?

Comment: @himself, @david: what about an old fashioned pascal object instead of a record or a class instance? No time to try myself (past my bedtime coz of early rise tomorrow).

Comment: @Marjan Probably behaves the same way as record plus in D2010 it will fail to clean up managed types!

Answer (score 1):

### I... think I did it

I hope Delphi developers see what they make their programmers do!

```
type
  PCallMaker = ^TCallMaker;
  TCallMaker = record
    Param1: integer;
    Param2: integer;
    function This: PCallMaker; inline;
    procedure Call; inline;
  end;

function TCallMaker.This: PCallMaker;
begin
  Result := @Self;
 { Record functions HAVE to have correct self-pointer,
  or they wouldn’t be able to modify data. }
end;

procedure TCallMaker.Call;
begin
  writeln(Param1, ' ', Param2);
end;

function CallMaker: TCallMaker; inline
begin
  Result.Param1 := 0;
  Result.Param2 := 0;
end;

procedure DoingSomeWorkHere;
var cm: TCallMaker;
begin
 {Test the assumption that cm is consistent}
  cm := CallMaker;
  if cm.This <> @cm then
    raise Exception.Create('This wasn''t our lucky day.');

 {Make a call}
  with CallMaker.This^ do begin
    Param1 := 100;
    Param2 := 500;
    Call;
  end;
end;
```

This works, preserves all the good points of the old version (speed, simplicity, small call overhead) but aren't there any hidden problems with this approach?

Comment: With this solution you'll have to change all usages of CallMaker anyway. So I'd suggest that you go the whole way and use an explicit variable like @David [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549594/delphi-2010-and-left-side-cannot-be-assigned-to-in-read-only-records-can-this/6549691#6549691). You won't notice any overhead and get rid of the ambiguity `with` introduces.

Comment: This looks simply terrible. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Make rich function calls possible. It's kind of long, so I've explained it here: http://pastebin.com/SER3aCdZ

Comment: Why don't you pass everything in to the function in a record? Why fight the language?

Comment: Point is, I wasn't fighting it until I received this blow by Delphi 2010 :) Anyway, yeah, records are fine with me except they still require additional variable. So I went this way. It wasn't "against the language" back then, it was "clever use of language".

Comment: This relies on the assumption that the temporary returned by `CallMaker` will live through the end of the enclosing `with` block. Find that guarantee documented somewhere, and I think you have your solution. Without that guarantee, you're no better off than you were before Delphi 2010, relying on a technicality of the compiler.

Comment: Ugliest delphi hack ever. Okay, well, maybe not. But in the top ten anyways.

Comment: @himself: It's not so "clever" when it makes code unstable and difficult to support - both of which you've now demonstrated.

Comment: @Argalatyr: Ok, so if Delphi 2012 deprecates "repeat...until", all the code that relied on it would be retrospectively declared "unstable and difficult to support". I get your idea.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Unfortunately you're right. The only way to not rely on implementation is probably "with CallMaker with This^ begin ... end; Call; end". This way Delphi can't release CallMaker until Call() executes.

Comment: @himself: I just quibble with you example as hyperbole, because "repeat...until" is explicitly supported; your approach represented dependence on an undocumented behavior (i.e. it's a hack, and the fallacy is to think that a hack is "clever" in the long term).  I don't mean to throw stones (we all do this), I just think this is a risk of such practices and instability with a version change shouldn't be a surprise.