# Record in TDictionary

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How can I use `record` in `TDictionary`?

```
TMyRec = record
    a: Integer;
    b: Integer;
end;

...

dictionary = TDictionary<String, TMyRec>.create();

...

dictionary[key].a := 30;<<<
```

Here the compiler gives an error: "Left side cannot be assigned to". How can I solve this problem without creating a separate function for writing `myFunc(a, b: Integer): TMyRec`?

Comment: Did you try assigning whole `dictionary[key] := someRec;` ?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620506/left-side-cannot-be-assigned-to-for-record-type-properties-in-delphi

Answer (score 4):

`dictionary[key]` returns a copy of the record held by the dictionary. The compiler prevents you from modifying that because it would serve no purpose.

As an aside, older versions of the program would accept your code and it was very confusing that the modification to the record would be lost. You'd make an assignment but nothing visible changed because what you assigned was a nameless local variable.

Clearly you intend to modify the record held in the collection. In order to do that you need to assign the entire record. Read the record from the collection into a local variable. Modify the local variable. Write the updated value back to the collection. Like so:

```
var
  rec: TMyRec;
...
rec := dictionary[key];
rec.a := 30;
dictionary[key] := rec;
```

One of the frustrating aspects of this is that the code needs to perform two dictionary lookups, even though we know that the second one will find the same record as the first one. Not even the mighty Spring4d dictionary can do this with a single lookup.

Comment: It would be possible if the dictionary could return a *pointer* to the stored record. Then no double lookup would be required. But AFAIK no dictionary I know supports this, and it is probably not so easy to code with generics anyway.

Comment: FWIW, a dictionary could cache the last key searched, and if the next search uses the same key, no new lookup is required. In scenarios like this, the same key is used twice, after all.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That's not how I would do it I think. I'd have something like an update method, `procedure UpdateValue(const Key: TKey; const UpdateProc: TUpdateProc<TValue>);` where `TUpdateProc` is passed by var a `TValue`. I've been discussing this in the context of the spring4d dictionary with Stefan.

Comment: You could have both. The specific update method for specialized scenarios, and the caching as a 'hidden' feature. The disadvantage of the latter is that the dictionary will always have to check if the key is the same so it can use the cache. Depending on the use, you will lose more cycles over that check than you will gain by hitting the cache. Maybe there is a third option, to have a method that returns a reference to the item?

Comment: @GolezTrol: that "third option" was my first. <g> Anything else, e..g the UpdateValue thing, or the cache, could indeed be slower than a simple pointer to the store item (doesn't have to be a record). I guess a combination of all three would be nice., so you could choose the one best suited to the situation.

Answer (score 3):

David Heffernans [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53553124/64082) is what you're after, but I would like to offer an additional warning. Records can have properties just like classes, with getters and setters, and if your record has such properties your code will compile, but it will still not change the actual record value.

```
TMyRec = record
private
  FA : integer;
  procedure SetA(const Value: integer);
  function GetA : integer;
public
  { Warning: When used on result from dictionary lookup, only the COPY will be 
    altered, not the actual record in the dictionary! }
  property A : integer read GetA write SetA; 
end;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked. Should it have been a comment?