# Delphi, record type property, record field assignment

Tags: delphi, properties, record

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999249/delphi-record-type-property-record-field-assignment-assignment-to-local-copy/54999452#54999452) by David Heffernan, he use assignment to read-only properties (see complete program example).
There are two property: RecDirect and RecFunction. Both are read-only.

My question is why would one write to something that is read-only?
Also I think properties are very flexible and useful. So why would one use properties and after all refer to corresponding underlying fields?

Comment: Not sure I understand your concerns but in this example he assigns a value to member of that property, not the property itself, and in the example he demonstrates some side effects of record type properties.

Comment: My concern is that _Properties provide control over access to an object's attributes_ [proof](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Properties_(Delphi)). It looks like record type properties are just break access control mechanism.

Comment: Read-only access is to the property itself, it's not propagated to members of instance that property points.

Comment: @MiroslavPenchev You said _Read-only access is to the property itself, it's not propagated to members of instance that property points._
Can you provide link to official documentation on this?

Comment: @Adriano: That's simply how it works in Delphi. For instance, an object variable is merely a pointer to the object. Even if you cannot change this variable, you can change the object itself.

Comment: I think if you re-read the answer carefully you'll see that there is never any attempt to write to a read only property. All you need is already in the answer you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

In the linked answer David did not write to read only property.

The `Obj.RecDirect.A := 21;` dos not write to a read only property.

What this does is to use `RedDirect` property first to retrieve reference to a Record object.

And then it uses `A` property of that referenced Record to write a value of 21 to `FA` field of that referenced Record. And if you take a look at property `A` definition in that record you can see that is defined as Read/Write property.